# R data.table how to normalize all rows

Tags: r, data.table, normalization

Trying to normalize all rows in the data frame such that

```
A B C      A   B   C
1 2 4 =>   1  .3  .6
2 2 5      2  .3  .7
3 4 6      3  .4  .6
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617619/normalize-each-row-of-data-table) returns a warning that it's coercing to an integer

```
outdf <- df[, names(df) := (.SD / rowSums(.SD)), .SDcols=x,by=y]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643820/how-to-change-type-of-target-column-when-doing-by-group-in-a-data-table-in-r) does nothing

```
outdf <- df[, names(df) := as.numeric(x)][,x:=(.SD / rowSums(.SD)), .SDcols=x,by=y][]
```

These are both close. Is there a better way to change types or a better way to normalize.
(data is ~42GB coming into this line so data.table is the way to go)

EDIT:

x and y

```
x <- names(data)[14:ncol(data)]
y <- names(data)[1]
```

Comment: What are `x` & `y` in your example? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @markus that has been updated to show

Comment: Not my downvote, but what is `data`? Can you create a data.table as part of your question that people can work with?

Comment: It is shape (634,~1000000) of ints like the toy example at the top of the question. it's A LOT of 1 hot encoded data that gets groupby'd(?) and normalized

Comment: The error appears to be within the x and y processing. If you are simply normalizing each row to sum to 1, what is the purpose of the by groups?

Comment: to ignore the factor in the first column,
removing that yeilded the right answer

Comment: The `by` argument was not the problem. Leaving it in even with a column name that is outside the .SDcols set, does not cause an error. (Which was the reason I rejected your proposed edit.)

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be over thinking it.  This seems to do what is desired:

```
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(A=c(1,2,2), B=c(2,2,4))
X[ , .SD/rowSums(.SD)]  
# using .SDcols can be used to make this selective
           A         B
1: 0.3333333 0.6666667
2: 0.5000000 0.5000000
3: 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

I didn't encounter any problems with assigning to X to accomplish the expected replacement.

Demonstrating the using `.SDcols` and `by` parameters does not affect this. (And noting that row oriented operations would not be expected to be affected through the use of `by` parameter, anyway.)

```
X <- data.table(ID =letters[1:3], A=c(1,2,2), B=c(2,2,4))
X <- rbind(X,X)  # so there are multiple items in the groups
X <- X[ , .SD/rowSums(.SD), .SDcols=c("A", "B"), by="ID"]
# Only effect of the `by="ID"` seem to be an alpha sort

> X
   ID         A         B
1:  a 0.3333333 0.6666667
2:  a 0.3333333 0.6666667
3:  b 0.5000000 0.5000000
4:  b 0.5000000 0.5000000
5:  c 0.3333333 0.6666667
6:  c 0.3333333 0.6666667
```